# How to make certain tab (screen) skippable in material top bar?

Tags: react-native

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Profile from "../components/Profile/Profile";
import Trips from "../components/Trips/MyTrips";
import Wallet from "../components/Wallet/Wallet";
import Booking from "../components/Booking/Booking";
import Summary from "../components/Summary/Summary";
import Colors from "../Shared/Colors";

bottomBarConfig = {
  Summary: {
    screen: Summary,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={
              focused
                ? require("./../assets/images/home_active.png")
                : require("./../assets/images/home_notactive.png")
            }
            size={25}
            color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "#808080"}
          />
        );
      },

      title: "Home"
    }
  },
  Trips: {
    screen: Trips,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={
              focused
                ? require("./../assets/images/mytrips_active.png")
                : require("./../assets/images/mytrips_notactive.png")
            }
            size={25}
            color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "#808080"}
          />
        );
      },

      style: {}
    }
  },
  Booking: {
    screen: () => null,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={require("./../assets/images/book.png")}
            size={55}
            style={{ height: 120 }}

            color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "#808080"}
          />
        );
      },
      showLabel: false,
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  },
  Wallet: {
    screen: Wallet,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={
              focused
                ? require("./../assets/images/mywallet_active.png")
                : require("./../assets/images/mywallet_notactive.png")
            }
            size={25}
            color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "#808080"}
          />
        );
      }
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={
              focused
                ? require("./../assets/images/more_active.png")
                : require("./../assets/images/more_notactive.png")
            }
            size={25}
            color={focused ? Colors.Primary : "#ff00ff"}
          />
        );
      }
    }
  }
};

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(bottomBarConfig, {
  tabBarPosition: "bottom",
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    upperCaseLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: Colors.Primary,
    inactiveTintColor: "gray",
    pressColor: Colors.Primary,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "none"
    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 10,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"
    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.Primary
    }
  }
});
const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default App;
```

[image]

This is a photo of what I want to execute(not what I have right now), bottom bar with big button in the middle.

For that I created screen for it and I will remove the label and style the image. But the problem I want user when swipes from tab 2 to tab 3 he actually goes to tab 4 not 3. I want this button to take user to another route.

So I want tab 3 to be skippable, no screen for it, I want it as just a button.

I am using create `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` because it has swipe feature and I already configured it to be positioned in bottom and I will be editing style of button in middle, just need to make skippable.